# How to integrate the feature of third party app (django-avatar) in my app?

Tags: python, django

I developed the user profile setting page. I don't know how to include the change avatar feature in the setting page ?

I use {% include avatar/add.html %} in the userprofile.html . I know it is wrong but I didn't find out any solution. Please help me.

Thank you in advance

Update: I want to change avatar feature on the same setting page. . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'avatar',
)
```

just put below code in your page

```
<a href="{% url 'avatar_change' %}">Change your avatar</a>
```

Comment: I don't want change to another page. I want to change avatar on the same setting page. How can I do it ?